# Devise with multiple User Models with single login form?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have 3 types of users called user,admin and business.

I have used rails4 with devise Gem.

I have created 3 devise model.now i have 3 different sign in pages.

Instead of this 3 different sign in screen,People should be login by single screen.

Please give me solution if you have.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Just make a Welcome page

Then, give links to each of the user type and call the respective sign in pages in the button or the link.

OR

what you can do is

create a single devise model and then assign the roles to the users.

for more refer to [Link](http://findnerd.com/account/#url=/list/view/Using-rolify-devise-and-cancan-gem-together-for-user-authorizations-and-access-in-rails/19354/)